# php - unlink() delete files/folders with checkboxes

Tags: php, file, download, directory

and happy holidays.
i am working on a small school project that needs to DELETE the selected with checkboxes files/folders. i got this php script giving the checkboxes to the specific file:

```
<?php

$path = "./user";
$dh = dir($path);
while( ($file=$dh->read()) !== false) {
    if( $file=="." || $file=="..")continue;
    $realfile = $path . "/" . $file;
    echo (is_dir($realfile))?  "<tr><td><a href='opendir.php?f=$file' title='Click to Open'>$file</a></td>":"<tr><td><a href='download.php?f=$file' title='Click to Download'>$file</a></td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo (is_file($realfile))? "<img src='file.jpg'/>" : "<img src='folder.jpg'/>";
    echo "</td><td>" .filesize($realfile)."</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='delete[]'/></td></tr>";
}
?>
```

and than i have the script into the profile page, that is confirming the DELETE (html form):

```
<form method="post" action="delete.php" ecntype="multipart/form-data">
Please confirm if you wish to delete the selected files :
<input type="submit" value="Detele selected files" onclick="return confirm('DELETE the selected?');" />
```

and the delete.php as well:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//to run PHP script on submit
    if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){

        foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected)
        {
            unlink($selected);
        }
    }
}
include 'profile.php';
?>
```

unfortunately it is not working the way i want to.... will be happy to get some help.
thank you

Comment: In your code there is no input field with the name "check_list" (or "check_list[]"). Maybe you just have to change input field names?

Comment: `ecntype` should be `enctype`

Comment: i change the ' echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='delete[]'/></td></tr>" to name="check_list" - as the same in the delete.php and still nothing happens :( i wounder if the information from the first part, the file 'table.php' is actually getting correct to the delete.php file..... echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='delete[]'/></td></tr>"